# Background worker cancelation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a timer and a background worker, which initiates on every timer tick. Sometimes I need for user to stop this workflow and call that same bg worker from a button click.

Since it is in Silverlight it is all async. BG worker make async Webservice call, which asynchronously returns data. 
I have done this, but it just feels wrong. What are best ways to handle that kind of situation?

```
button_click_event(..)
{
 _loadTimer.Stop();
                 _worker.CancelAsync();
                 _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

WebService call

```
public void GetUserStats(DateTime start, DateTime end, Action<IEnumerable<IUserStats>, Exception> callback)
    {
        _context.GetUserStatsCompleted += ContextGetUserStatsCompleted;
        _context.GetUserStatsAsync(start,end,callback);
    }

 void ContextGetUserStatsCompleted(object sender, GetUserStatsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var callback = e.UserState as Action<IEnumerable<IUserStats>, Exception>;
            Exception error = null;
            var result = new ObservableCollection<IUserStats>();
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                result = e.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                error = e.Error;
            }
            _context.GetUserStatsCompleted -= ContextGetUserStatsCompleted;
            callback(result, error);
        }
```

and my worker

```
void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            TicketService.GetUserStats(StartDate, EndDate, (result, error) =>
            {

                StreamHolder = result;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Show your code for making the Web Service call. If you are already calling the web service asynchronously, I don't see why you would need a `BackgroundWorker` at all.

Comment: I agree with Robert, but would  also add that, have the result of the asycn call check a global flag off the model view (if mvvm) which is set by the button click to throw away the results.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is there because i need to call WS every 30 seconds. Is there a better way to do it? And yes its mvvm

Answer (score 4):

Firs of all, you should always check to see if your worker is running, prior to attempting to run it again. If you don't then it's possible that your application will throw an exception.

```
if(!_worker.IsBusy) 
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Second of all, just calling CancelAsync() is not enough to cancel the current operation of the background worker. You will have to add code to the background worker's DoWork event handler. (In your case WorkerDoWork)

```
if(_worker.CancelationPending == true)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

You can read more about the proper way to use a background worker here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: No problem, please mark the question as Answered if it is by clicking the check mark below the downvote icon.